# How to restart this css animation when Browser Tab is active

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i want to restart this css animation when Browser Tab is active, so How to restart this css animation.
my purpose is that when-when we comes in this animation tab the `.r1 DIV box` everytime animate.
Just like this example: here the bobble restart when we are in active tab position.
Check this: https://codepen.io/repzeroworld/pen/EmjLGP  
https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/vmOMpx
**here is no relation from this example to my problem, But i am just telling you for example only.**

My code is:

```css
.r1 {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 6px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.r1 {
    animation: bounceInRight 1400ms both
}

@keyframes bounceInRight {

    from,
    60%,
    75%,
    90%,
    to {
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    }

    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate3d(3000px, 0, 0);
    }

    60% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate3d(-25px, 0, 0);
    }

    75% {
        transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
    }

    90% {
        transform: translate3d(-5px, 0, 0);
    }

    to {
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="r1">This text is the content of the box..</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So when you press tab you want to restart the animation?

Comment: i mean when i switch the Tab where animation code is running, then animation restart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Javascript. Particularly

```js
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {

    if(document.visibilityState === "visible" ){
    //restart animation
     }
    else{
    //don't restart 
    }

})
```

more on visibility change here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event

Comment: can you explain in detail plz plz plz... humble request
thanks a lot in advance

Comment: it's working but onw time only, again & again i want when when tab is active the animation is must be restart.